# python - iscapitalized()

Tags: python, uppercase

Can we define a function iscaptialized() to check if the first letter of the input string is in upper case?

The below code is not so elegant as I would have to repeat the ifelse for all the 26 alphabets. Is there an alternate/elegant way to define?

```
    def iscapitalized():
        if word.startswith('A'):
           print('True')
       else:
           print('False')

    word = input('Enter a word:')
    iscapitalized()
```

Comment: [isupper()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper)

Comment: `word[0].isupper()`

Comment: `isupper()`: "Return true if **all** cased characters in the string are uppercase and there is at least one cased character, false otherwise"

Comment: @LutzHorn thats why you use the `[0]`

Comment: @GertKommer has the powerful way to do it `def iscapitalized(word):
 return word[0].isupper()`

Comment: yeah word[0].isupper() is easy! Thank you @Gert